# UIViewController is covered by another fullscreen view controller, but not removed from the hierarchy

Tags: ios, uikit

**Participants**:

- `A` and `C` are view controllers with solid background. Nothing is changed from the default settings.
- `B` is a view controller with a semi-transparent background. It's supposed to cover part of view controller it is presented over. ModalPresentation style is `overFullScreen`

**Short story**: `A` presents `B`, `B` presents `C`. `viewWillDisappear` is never called on `A`

**Long story**:

- `A` is on screen
- `A` presents `B` with a following call: `self.present(B, animated: true)`
- Both `A` and `B` are visible on screen. `viewWillDisappear` method of `A` is **not** invoked, which is expected as it's still visible
- `B` presents `C` with a following call: `self.present(C, animated: true)`
- `C` appears on screen, covers everything, it's presentation mode is `fullscreen`.
- `B` is removed from view hierarchy. `viewWillDisappear` method of `B` is called
- Inspecting view hierarchy I can see that `A` is still there and `viewWillDisappear` is never called on `A`, but it's not visible either as it's covered by a fullscreen view controller.

I expect that `A` is removed from the hierarchy along with `B`, as none of them are visible if are covered with `fullscreen` view controller.

Is it a bug of UIKit or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Per the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/1621506-overfullscreen), this is the expected behavior of `UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen`. Another style – `.fullScreen` – seems closer to the behavior you want.

Comment: Presenting A (.fullScreen) -> B (.overFullscreen, I want A to be partially covered at this moment)  -> C (.fullScreen) results in A -> C being in the hierarchy. B is removed as expected, but why A wasn't removed as it is also covered by a .fullScreen view controller?